# create a backup table with million records

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I want to move old records from TABLEA to TABLEA_AUDIT. TABLEA have around  1.5 million records and it have two nested tables.

No of Records : 1557951
Size :  1024 MB

I tried it by,

1.using Create table as select * from

```
CREATE TABLE
TABLEA_AUDIT
COLUMN TABLEA_STAGE NOT SUBSTITUTABLE AT ALL LEVELS
NESTED TABLE TABLEA_STAGES STORE AS AUDIT_TABLEA_STAGES,
NESTED TABLE TABLEA_MODELS STORE AS AUDIT_TABLEA_MODELS
AS
SELECT *
FROM
TABLEA
WHERE COULMN1 IS NOT NULL
AND TRUNC(UPDATED_DT) < '01-MAR-18';
```

Result : 2hours of waiting and didnt get any result

2.Tried CREATE TABLE AS with no logging by follwoing below blog.
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_fast_copy_data_oracle_table.htm

Result : 2hours of waiting and didnt get any result

3.Developed a new procedure to copy the records and created a new DBMS_JOB

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE TABLEA_AUDIT AS SELECT * FROM TABLEA';
```

Result : Job is running for more than 2hours and no result.

4.Created the table and developed a procedure to insert bulk records

```
set serveroutput on size unlimited
set timing on
declare 
type audit_type is table of TABLEA%rowtype;
v_type audit_type;
CURSOR temp_cur is
select  *
FROM TABLEA a
WHERE COLUMN1 IS NOT NULL
AND TRUNC(UPDATED_DT) < '01-MAR-18';
BEGIN

    OPEN  temp_cur;
    / collect data in the collection /
    FETCH temp_cur BULK COLLECT INTO v_type;
    / close the pointer /
    CLOSE temp_cur;

    FORALL i in v_type.first .. v_type.last
    INSERT INTO TABLEA_AUDIT VALUES v_type(i);

    FORALL i in v_type.first .. v_type.last
    DELETE  FROM TABLEA WHERE PRIMARY_KEY_COL = v_type(i).PRIMARY_KEY_COL;               

    COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Thanks.

Comment: `AND TRUNC(UPDATED_DT) < '01-MAR-18'` - wrong way to do date comparison. Simply use  `UPDATED_DT < DATE '2018-03-01'`

Comment: @KaushikNayak Noted bro.

Comment: Don't we backup and restore that table and rename the existing to `TABLEA_AUDIT` ?

Comment: @Susang But its taking too long to back up the table.

Answer (score 0):

Bro try this

```
--MSSQL
    select * into TABLEA_AUDIT from TABLEA

--FOR oracle (large amount of data )
Create table TABLEA_AUDIT
As
Select * 
from TABLEA 
where 1=2;

Insert into TABLEA_AUDIT
Select * from TABLEA;
```

Comment: I hope it better for oracle first create table then insert data. Code update above.

Comment: But as the initial table have nested table in it , it took longer than expected. I have only 2 hours to apply the same in production.

Comment: for nested table repeat the same process. it will allow inserting after insert data in the primary table. but before inserting change Relationship.

Comment: Dear @m-danish,  I have tried the same, Please refer point 1. But it took some time and didnt get any results.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest [Data Pump](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/dp_overview.htm#g1015896).

First, using the Export data pump *export* the table. In the next step, import it (using Import data pump - who'd guess?), using the `REMAP_TABLE` parameter.

Here's a simple example based on Scott's EMP table (I've removed superfluous lines to make it easier to read):

### Export:

```
c:\Temp>expdp scott/tiger@xe tables=emp directory=ext_dir dumpfile=emp.dmp

Export: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Pon Tra 30 14:45:18 2018

Starting "SCOTT"."SYS_EXPORT_TABLE_01":  scott/********@xe tables=emp directory=ext_dir dumpfile=emp.dmp
Estimate in progress using BLOCKS method...
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
Total estimation using BLOCKS method: 64 KB
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/INDEX
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/CONSTRAINT/CONSTRAINT
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/INDEX_STATISTICS
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/CONSTRAINT/REF_CONSTRAINT
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/STATISTICS/TABLE_STATISTICS
. . exported "SCOTT"."EMP"                               8.484 KB      12 rows
Master table "SCOTT"."SYS_EXPORT_TABLE_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
******************************************************************************
Dump file set for SCOTT.SYS_EXPORT_TABLE_01 is:
  C:\TEMP\EMP.DMP
Job "SCOTT"."SYS_EXPORT_TABLE_01" successfully completed at 14:45:20


c:\Temp>
```

### Import:

```
c:\Temp>impdp scott/tiger@xe remap_table=emp:emp_bkp directory=ext_dir dumpfile=emp.dmp exclude=constraint

Import: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Pon Tra 30 14:50:09 2018

Master table "SCOTT"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
Starting "SCOTT"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01":  scott/********@xe remap_table=emp:emp_bkp directory=ext_dir dumpfile=emp.dmp exc
lude=constraint
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
. . imported "SCOTT"."EMP_BKP"                           8.484 KB      12 rows
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/INDEX
ORA-31684: Object type INDEX:"SCOTT"."PK_EMP" already exists
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/INDEX_STATISTICS
ORA-39111: Dependent object type INDEX_STATISTICS skipped, base object type INDEX:"SCOTT"."PK_EMP" already exists
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/STATISTICS/TABLE_STATISTICS
Job "SCOTT"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01" completed with 2 error(s) at 14:50:11


c:\Temp>
```

Note that the primary key constraint creation failed, as the constraint with that name already exists in the original table.

The result:

```
c:\Temp>sqlplus scott/tiger@xe

SQL> select * From emp_Bkp;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE          SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17.12.1980        800                    20
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20.02.1981       1600        300         30
      7521 WARD       SALESMAN        7698 22.02.1981       1250        500         30
      7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839 02.04.1981       2975                    20
      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        7698 28.09.1981       1250       1400         30
      7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         7839 01.05.1981       2850                    30
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 09.06.1981       2450                    10
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17.11.1981       5000                    10
      7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        7698 08.09.1981       1500          0         30
      7900 JAMES      CLERK           7698 03.12.1981        950                    30
      7902 FORD       ANALYST         7566 03.12.1981       3000                    20
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 23.01.1982       1300                    10

12 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Once again, the two commands you should use:

```
expdp scott/tiger@xe tables=emp directory=ext_dir dumpfile=emp.dmp

impdp scott/tiger@xe remap_table=emp:emp_bkp directory=ext_dir dumpfile=emp.dmp exclude=constraint
```

Try it, see how it works.

Comment: I want both MAIN and AUDIT tables

Comment: OK. What's stopping you?

Comment: How about the nested table?

Comment: @Littefoot Im moving data only after  '01-MAR-18'; Will remap have both the tables.

Comment: You'd remap both tables. As of nested tables: if it was a "full" export, I'm sure it would be OK. With a table-mode one, I can't tell as I never tried it. Create a small test case (a table with a few rows) and try it. I *hope* it'll be OK, as good people in Oracle already thought of such cases.

Comment: My requirement is to create two new nested tables and move the data. This method is very useful when there is no nested tables in it. But in this case I'm struck with the nested table

Comment: So, you actually tried it and it didn't work? Sorry to hear that, I was hoping that this approach might be a good way to do your job.

Comment: is there any method to insert data from dmp file?ie, I have already created the table and nested table

Comment: Apart from Import? No, there is not.